# How to convert the Current User Time from String to DateTime data type?

Tags: apex, datetime, format

I have to populate the **Current User Time-Zone** DateTime in a DateTime field. I am trying this :

```
String str = datetime.now().format();
DateTime d = Datetime.valueOf(datetime.now().format());
DateTime dtm =  (DateTime) DateTime.parse(str);
system.debug('datetime.now().format() = ' + str);
system.debug('Datetime.valueOf(datetime.now().format()) = ' + d);
system.debug('DateTime.parse(str) = ' + dtm);
```

But the problem is that after using **format()** it is giving the String format and converting it into DateTime using **valueOf()** & **parse()** giving the PST time which is the ORG Timezone, whereas I want the Current User time-zone DateTime.
How can I get the **CurrentUser Time-Zone** DateTime in **DateTime** Data Type?

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Please update the code. What is 'str'?

Comment: I have edited the code.

Comment: no, actually it was small edit, to mention 'str' variable. I am still stuck in this.

Comment: I was able to solve the same issue with solution from link shared by David.